# Execute batch update faster

Tags: java, oracle, spring-batch

In an old project, I have a table with 3 indices on 3 columns, I am executing batch queries (~= 5000 update queries) like `UPDATE mytable set mycolumn = 'blah' when myIndexedColumn = 'someId'`.

The executeBatch command, takes 1h:30 approximately, I use oracle 11g database, and Java 6, Spring batch also. The concerned table holds 1 700 000 rows.

```
Statement ps = null;
Connection connection = null;
    try {
        int counter = 0;
        connection = myDatasource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        ps = connection.createStatement();

        for (String request : myListOfRequests) {
            ps.addBatch(request);       
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("My Errors : {}", ex.getMessage());
    } finally {

        if (ps != null) {
            ps.clearBatch(); 
            ps.close(); 
        }

        if (connection != null) connection.close();
    }
```

I have dropped the indices, but I didn't noticed a significant difference. I cannot use modern technologies. Also deleting and rebuilding a new table is not a secured task. So have you an idea how I can improve this task?

Comment: What about a [prepared statement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) with a batch of parameters instead of a batch of statements (also [here for spring](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_batch_operation.htm))? Saves the parsing for each of them on the db side, and network traffic too.

Comment: and be sure that there are indexes on the columns, and that the optimizer uses them, if as you say, just updating 5k rows out of 1.7M rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, originally posted by [jawad abbassi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1646674/jawad-abbassi) in the question:

Thanks to @curiosa, I have used preparedStatement instead of a statement in this way:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
Connection connection = null;
String sql =  "UPDATE MYTABLE SET COLUMN1 = ? WHERE COLUMN2 = ?";

try {

    connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (MyBean bean : myListOfBeans) {

        ps.setBigDecimal(1, bean.getColumn1());
        ps.setString(2, bean.getColumn2());
        ps.addBatch();

    }
    ps.executeBatch();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    LOGGER.error("My errors : {}", ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        connection.commit();
        ps.close(); 
        connection.close();
    }
}
```